# Blazor C# date shows as 1/1/0001 12:00:00Am

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm completely fresh to Blazor and have just dived into a project.

I'm using ORM to pull up data from a database. For some reason when I return the data, it is being shown as 1/1/0001 12:00:00Am

This is how I grab the data from DB

```
string sql = "Select top Value1, Value2, Value_DateTime from DBO.T_1";
return _db.LoadData<Model1, dynamic>(sql, new { });
```

And this is how I try to populate a table with a value, in .Razor page

```
<td>@Value.Value_DateTime</td>
```

All other data appears correctly. When I run the query in SSMS, it shoes correct dates.

EDIT:

```
 Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters);
```

Comment: What is `_db.LoadData`? What is `Model1`?

Comment: What is the field datatype in SQL for the field that stores the date (`datetime`, `smalldatetime`, etc)?

Comment: That's DateTime.MinValue; implies that the loading or mapping process skipped your datetime, leaving it with the default value for the type

Comment: @CoolBots - Datetime in SQL, and in my Model I use DateTime as well

Comment: @CaiusJard any idea why? All other fields, that just happen to be string are showing up correctly

Comment: @RufusL where are you seeing the def of LoadData?

Comment: @RufusL updated question

Comment: @CaiusJard Ah, thanks! My brain transferred the type specifications for the generic types as types for the arguments to the method...comment deleted. :)

Comment: It could be that the name of the property is different in than the name of the column in the db. Try to use strong typed models instead of `dynamic` to avoid pitfalls like this. I also would try to use some commonly used ORM like Dapper or EF Core for data access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blazor C# date shows as 1/1/0001 12:00:00Am

You are showing a DateTime that has not been initialized. Somewhere in your code you are simply not moving the data from the database into the field that you then show out. Sadly, your code is so non-standard I will not debug it - especially because of unneeded use of dynamics - but somewhere there you make a mistake.

Comment: I am following along a tutorial by IamTimCorey on youtube. He has an Intro To Blazor tutorial. I'm basically following the same exact approach he is showing, using Dapper but when I try to select a datetime field, it comes up with 1/1/0001

Comment: That is interesting. This must be as bad a tutorial as I ahve ever seen, at least in regards to data access. I basically NEVER use dynamic. Maybe once in - 10 years or so. This seriously looks like the field put out is simply not initialized. Use step by step in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be incompatibility between SQL `DateTime` datatype and C# `System.DateTime` struct. There is an alternative version: `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime` struct - switching to that struct in your Model *should*™ fix your problem.

Here's the docs link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Relevant excerpt:

> ...The `SqlDateTime` structure has a different underlying data structure from its corresponding .NET Framework type, `DateTime`...

Comment: Ah, you are aware that this is bascailly showing a NON INITIALIZED DATETIME?

Comment: @TomTom Yes, but I think the *reason* is the wrong type being used in the model. It can be something else, of course -as you mentioned, debugging the code is... going to be rather difficult. I updated my answer to be slightly less assertive, lol, as I can't prove correctness - OP needs to look into it on their end.